# How to avoid unnecessary initialization in helper function returning an object?

Tags: swift, initialization

I have a helper function called `fileByIndex`. This function takes an index parameter, and then uses this parameter to find an existing object, and returns this existing object. In this process, the code initializes an object with `var file = File()` line, then assigns an existing object to this reference. Here the initialization is actually unnecessary. I wonder if there is any way to avoid this unnecessary initialization & deinitialization.

I thought of (1) Creating a dummy `File` object for this purpose in global context (2) Giving this dummy object to this helper function as an `inout` parameter and returning it, but I feel this is not a good approach too.

Is there a proper way to avoid this?

```
class File {

}

let newFile1 = File()
let newFile2 = File()
let oldFile1 = File()
let oldFile2 = File()

var newFiles = [newFile1, newFile2]
var oldFiles = [oldFile1, oldFile2]


func fileByIndex(index: Int) -> File {

    var file = File()

    if index > 0 {
        file = newFiles[index]
    } else {
        file = oldFiles[index]
    }

    return file

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just declare the variable and not give it value:

```
func fileByIndex(index: Int) -> File {

    var file: File

    if index > 0 {
        file = newFiles[index]
    } else {
        file = oldFiles[index]
    }

    return file

}
```

In fact, `file` could be declared as a `let` in this case:

```
let file: File
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator like this.

```
func fileByIndex(index: Int) -> File {

    return index > 0 ? newFiles[index] : oldFiles[index]

}
```